# Annoying issue with Rails migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-migration

Its not a problem but more like an annoying step which i have to repeat every time i made a mistake. I created a migration which like this:

```
class CreateSubmissions < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :submissions do |t|
      t.references :student, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.references :assignment, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.references :question, index: true, foreign_key: true

      t.text :code

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_index :submissions, [:student_id, :assignment_id, :question_id], unique: true
  end
end
```

try to rub `rake db:migrate` and it give me error that index name is too long and more, i change that line to this

```
add_index :submissions, [:student_id, :assignment_id, :question_id],
                             unique: true, name: 'index_submissions'
```

and again try to execute `rake db:migrate` at that time it give me error that `submission_student_index` already exists (because the first time it created the table but throw exception while adding index) i tried to rollback so that i can execute whole `submissions` table and index together but unfortunately it rollback my previous migration (in some cases a previous table or index or column).

For that i have to manually go to the database and drop that `submissions` table and then execute `rake db:migrate` to create `submissions` table along with the all the index and also that previous migration. Its annoying to go back to the database and manually drop the table, i don't know if i am doing something wrong or there is some better way to this.

Comment: Adding the index in a separate migration might have avoided this problem, but whether that'd be considered a good practice, I don't know. It might have other drawbacks that I'm not thinking of right now.

Comment: That could be a temporary solution.